# Rotation transform animation not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, transformation, image-rotation

I am trying to make a small game in Flutter in which I have to rotate a `FittedBox` (parent of a image) which is inside `Grid` as shown in below code.

```
child: new AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: animationController,
    child: new InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        // setState(
        //   () {
            widget._angleCode = getNextDegree(widget._angleCode);
            animationController.forward();
            //checkAnswer();
        //   },
        // );
      },
      child: new FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: new Image.asset(getImageByCode(widget._image),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {

      animationController.value = getAngleByCode(widget._angleCode); //returns 0,.5,.75 consequtively
      return new Transform.rotate(
        angle: animationController.value * 2 * pi,
        child: _widget,
      );
    },
  ),
```

Although above code do rotating the image **BUT** without transformation animation. I have overrided my class with `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` and implemented initState() as below:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    //animationController.forward();
  }
```

How can I animate my rotation?

Comment: Do you want to rotate an image or the outer container?

Comment: @snj Thanks for quick reply. Outer container Fitted box just have one child which is image. And rotating outer container will do the work.

Comment: Please check the answer. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  double target = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTapHandler() {
    target += 0.25;
    if (target > 1.0) {
      target = 0.25;
      _controller.reset();
    }
    _controller.animateTo(target);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: _onTapHandler,
          child: RotationTransition(
            turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: SizedBox(
                child: new Text("Lorem ipsum"),
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I want but with animation while rotation transformation. Right now your code is rotating with steps(just painting at different angle). I want smooth rotation in between 0->90->180->270->360(0)

Comment: Tried. Still not have the animation effect. On just single tap it should rotate from 0 degree to 90 degree in 2 secs with animation. Not immediately repaint to 90 degree. I guess we have to use AnimationController

Comment: Please check now

Comment: yes! You did it. Now I have to integrate this in my project. Thanks buddy.

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Perfect!